# Proving The Diamond Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

We have the diamond lemma as follows:

Let $\rightarrow$ be relation on a set $P$. Let $\twoheadrightarrow$ be the reflexive transitive closure of $\rightarrow$ and $\sim$ the equivalence relation generated by $\rightarrow$ then if we have the following two conditions:

1) There is no infinite sequence $a_0\rightarrow a_1\rightarrow \ldots $

2) Let $a, b, c \in P$ be such that $a \rightarrow b$ and $a \rightarrow c$. Then there exists $d \in P$ such that $b \twoheadrightarrow d$ and $c \twoheadrightarrow d$.

Then every $\sim$-clas contains a unique element $a$ such that $a\not\rightarrow b$ for all $b\in P$.

Now I am told to proceed in the following way:

Consider $Q(a):=\{b\in P|a\twoheadrightarrow b\}$. Then let $R$ be the set of elements $a\in A$ such that $Q(a)$ doesn't have a least element.

I really have no idea where to go from here.

Thanks for any help

Comment: If an equivalence class contains a successor for every element, i.e. a $b$ for every $a$ such that $a \to b$, then there's an infinite sequence, no? Just start at some element and continue to pick successor - you always can, by the hypothesis. Thus (1) guarantees that there is at *least* one $a$ with the desired property.

Comment: Now assume you have two successor-less elements $b_1, b_2$. Then they cannot have a common predecessor, i.e. there can be no $a$ with $a \twoheadrightarrow a_1, a \twoheadrightarrow a_2$, since that would violate (2). But if they don't have a common predecessor, and no successor at all, how did they end up in the same equivalence class?

Comment: @fgp why if two elements have a common predecessor does that violate 2)?

Comment: Because you'd then have the situation that $a \twoheadrightarrow b_1$, $a \twoheadrightarrow b_2$. But $b_1,b_2$ have no successor, i.e. there are no $c_1,c_2$ with $b_1 \to c_1, b_2 \to c_2$, and thus obviously also no *single* $c$ with $b_1 \twoheadrightarrow c, b_2 \twoheadrightarrow c$. That contradicts (2).

Comment: @fgp but why does $b_1\twoheadrightarrow c_1$ give that $b_1\rightarrow c_1$?

Comment: Um, because $\twoheadrightarrow$ is the transitive closure of $\to$. That means that exactly if there's a finite sequence $a \to a_1 \to a_2 \to \ldots \to a_n \to b$, then $a \twoheadrightarrow b$.

Comment: @fgp but condition 2) only applies if $a\rightarrow b_1$ and $a\rightarrow b_2$. If we have a chain $a\rightarrow a_1 \ldots \rightarrow b$ then we would need to apply condition 2) to each step of the chain right? I think that is what this $Q(a)$ is attempting to avoid?

Comment: Hm, true, I missed an induction step there...

Comment: Btw, your definition of $Q(a)$ is a bit weird - where does the $A$ come from?

Comment: @fgp Sorry that was meant to be $P$. Yeah I think it's an induction step with a subtlety about making sure chains stop after nice numbers of steps or something, however the way I am asked to answer this question is using this $Q(a)$ and I have no idea where to proceed with it, every time I do I just end up back at the induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q(a)$ and $R$ be as in the OP. It will suffice to show
the following lemma (which immediately allows one to define
inductively a sequence contradicting property (1)) :

**Lemma.** If $r\in R$, then there is a $s\in P$ such that
$r\to s$ and $s\in R$.

**Proof of lemma.** Suppose by contradiction that 
$I=\lbrace b\in P | r \to b\rbrace$ does not contain
any element of $R$. Then for any $x\in I$, $Q(x)$ has a least
element $\lambda(x)$. By property (2), for any $x,y\in I$
there is a $d_{x,y}\in Q(x)\cap Q(y)$. We then have
$ d_{x,y}\twoheadrightarrow \lambda(x)$ and
$ d_{x,y}\twoheadrightarrow \lambda(y)$, so applying (2)
again there is a $\mu\in Q(\lambda(x))\cap Q(\lambda(y))$. But since
$\lambda(x)$ and $\lambda(y)$ are least elements, we must
have $\mu=\lambda(x)=\lambda(y)$ for any $x,y\in I$. It is now
clear that $\mu$ is the least element of $Q(r)$, contradicting
$r\in R$. The lemma is proved.